# Angularjs + Requirejs. Provider error

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am new to angularjs and requirejs, and I got stuck with next error. I saw a couple of similar questions, but still can't get rid of this error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: versionProvider <- version <- appVersionDirective
```

My app.js:

```
 define([
     'angular',
     './controllers/index',
     './directives/index',
     './filters/index',
     './services/index'
 ], function (ng) {
     'use strict';
     return ng.module('app', [
         'ngRoute',
         'app.controllers',
         'app.filters',
         'app.directives',
         'app.services'
     ]);
});
```

directives/index.js:

```
define([
    './myDirective'
], function () {});
```

directives/module.js:

```
define(['angular', '../services/module'], function (ng, services) 
{
    'use strict';
    return ng.module('app.directives', ['app.services']);
});
```

directives/myDirective.js:

```
define(['./module'], function (directives) 
{
    'use strict';
    directives.directive('appVersion', ['version', function (version) 
    {
            return function(scope, elm, attrs) 
            {
                elm.text(version);
            };
        }]);
});
```

Is there some mistakes in code? or my approach is wrong? If someone can help I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular is complaining because by the time execution reaches `directives/myDirective.js`, it cannot find a definition for your `version` service. Check where the definition of `version` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was exactly like [miqid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618117/angularjs-requirejs-provider-error?noredirect=1#comment38157956_24618117) said, I messed up with version definition in my services.

Now it s looks like this:

```
services.value('version', '0.2');
```

And works without any errors.